# Analytical Solution for 1D Heat Diffusion on Cylindrical/Spherical Coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates, heat-equation, error-function, cylindrical-coordinates

I would like some insight in how to solve the following equations analytically:

$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha}{r} \frac{\partial^2 (r T)}{\partial r^2} \\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 (r^2 T)}{\partial r^2}
$$

Subject to the following Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$$T(r=0,t) = T_0; \\
T(r=\infty,t) = 0 \hspace{1mm} \textrm{or} \hspace{1mm} T(r=\infty,t) = T_{\infty}$$

I already know that the solution for the cartesian problem, namely

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2} $$

Is something of the likes of $1-erf(r/(\sqrt{2\alpha t}))$ for $T_{\infty}=0$, so I would guess it is not that different for other coordinate systems? I'm trying to solve it myself but I figured I could find some help here. I'm only interested for the solution for $r>0, t>0$. I'm sorry I can't provide more input since I'm mostly concerned with numerical solutions of PDE's, but for my implementation it would be much quicker to have an analytical solution. Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: You could try a [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Nuclear_physics) in one of the coordinates and solve the resulting ODE, or try finding a [similarity solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similar_solution), or possibly a coordinate or functional transform.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve these equations is by variable separation. I will show this just for the first case being similar for the other. You have to choose your solution in the form
$$
T(r,t)=R(r)\Theta(t).
$$
By inserting this into the equation one gets
$$
\frac{1}{\Theta(t)}\frac{\partial\Theta(t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\alpha}{rR(r)}\frac{\partial^2(rR(r))}{\partial r^2}.
$$
By introducing a constant $\lambda$, one gets the following two equations
$$
\frac{\partial\Theta(t)}{\partial t}=-\lambda\Theta(t)
$$
and
$$
\alpha\frac{\partial^2(rR(r))}{\partial r^2}=-\lambda rR(r).
$$
Then, a particular solution has the form
$$
T_\lambda(r,t)=\left(A\frac{e^{i\lambda\alpha r}}{r}+B\frac{e^{-i\lambda\alpha r}}{r}\right)e^{-\lambda t}.
$$
The parameter $\lambda$ is fixed by the boundary conditions. In your case, the condition $T(r=0,t)=T_0$ yields only the possibility $A=-B$ but seems inconsistent otherwise.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the input. What do you mean by "seems inconsistent otherwise"? You mean that for $T(r=0,t)=T_0$ there seems to be only the solution $A=-B$?

Comment: No, that the exponential in time cannot be disposed with. You should take the trivial case $\lambda=0$ with the static solution $A/r$ but this is singular for $r=0$. Generally, in Dirichlet boundary conditions this is 0 and you get a set of values of $\lambda$.

Comment: What if I change the condition to a known, fixed value : $T(r=R_d,t)=T_r$?

Comment: I would rather choose$T(r=R_d,t=0)=T_r$.